# Can you make a Native Libary from LUA for iOS, Android, WP8?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8, lua, native

**My Goal**

Make a SDK for each native device such as Android, iOS, and WP8. I would not like to have to use 3 laguages to produce 3 native SDK's

**Question**

Now my question is can LUA be compiled into native libarys and exported such as a Jar or DLL?

**Alternate Question**

If I can't make native libarys, I will likely want to wrap LUA code inside a native libary that I make and bind functions to expose LUA / Native code. So my alternate question is there a LUA libary that is avabile for all the mobile platforms?

*I don't want to have to use one lua libary for iOS and one for Android if possible.*

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say, if you truely want portability in a single codebase, there's only two languages-  C and C++.  Nothing else is as fully supported.  You may be able to write LUA apps for each, but you won't be able to export them as libraries-  at least not something that's dynamically linked like a dll.  If you're looking for statically linked, maybe-  but Apple isn't really nice about letting you use languages other than the C family.

Comment: That part about Apple used to be true for a while, but not any more. See Corona  SDK for instance, which uses Lua.